# Cannot make two simple JS code to work at the same time

Tags: javascript, function, onload

I've basic knowledge of JS. I'm trying to make the two functions below to work together but I cannot find a solution. It's either one or the other that work but not the two together.

```
<script>
function random_string(size){
var str = "";
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++){
    str += random_character();
}
return str;
}
function random_character() {
var chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTUVWXYZ";
return chars.substr( Math.floor(Math.random() * 62), 1);
}
window.onload = function () {
var partnerurl = document.getElementById('field1');
              uniqueid = document.getElementById('field2');
              uniqueid.value = random_string(15);

            partnerurl.value = "www.website.com"+uniqueid.value


};
</script>


<script>
var defaultHiddenFieldNameValue = "";
function getQueryStringParamValue(strQStrParam) {
var strURL = document.location.href;
var strQStrParamValue = "";
if (strURL.indexOf('?') != -1)
{
strQStrParamValue = strURL.substr(strURL.indexOf('?') + 1);
if (strQStrParamValue.indexOf(strQStrParam) != -1)
{
strQStrParamValue = strQStrParamValue.substr(strQStrParamValue.indexOf(strQStrParam));
strQStrParamValue = strQStrParamValue.substr(strQStrParamValue.indexOf('=') + 1);
if (strQStrParamValue.indexOf('&') != -1)
strQStrParamValue = strQStrParamValue.substr(0, strQStrParamValue.indexOf('&'));
return strQStrParamValue;
}else{
strQStrParamValue = defaultHiddenFieldNameValue;
return strQStrParamValue;
}
}else{
strQStrParamValue = defaultHiddenFieldNameValue;
return strQStrParamValue;
}
}
// Form name goes here
var form = "formname";
function setCampaign(){
var elqForm = document.forms[form];
//repeat for each field to populate
elqForm.elements['src'].value = getQueryStringParamValue('src');
}
window.onload = setCampaign;
</script>
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Cheers,

FX

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: None, I just have the second code to populate the src fields but the first one doesn't triggered.

Comment: Can you add the HTML to the question? Or better yet, can you create a jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TN267/

Comment: As a side note, that is some frightening HTML. Is there any particular reason you're not using a CSS stylesheet instead of all those inline styles?

Comment: I agree... and I cannot edit the form html code. It's a tool we use that is building all this automatically. I guess it's easy to use but when you need to tweaks things it gets complicated...

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample here you are missing a semicolon on the last line of the onload function.

I also don't see you declaring uniqueid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Each of the code works fine separately. It's when I put the two together that I only have the second one that works.

Comment: Did you add the semicolon and check if it helps? Some interpreters will not continue executing the script if it runs into an exception due to a missing semicolon. This could mean it stops before it gets to the second part of your script. Also try to declare uniqueid as well. It is best to not leave such things up to the interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

Your random string function works fine, its just getting the `window.onload` to fire that I had problems with.

Here is a demostration of your random string working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Jimmery/tv87X/

I would suggest loading jQuery with this line in your HTML:

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var partnerurl = $('field1');
    var uniqueid = $('field2');
    uniqueid.val(random_string(15));
    partnerurl.val("www.website.com/"+uniqueid.val());
};
```